# How to set the badge text in a chrome extension from the content script?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script

It is possible to set the badge text from a background script. I was wondering if it was possible to do so from a content script.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's [not possible](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). You need to [message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple) a background page to do it for you.

> However, content scripts have some limitations. They cannot:
>
> Use `chrome.*` APIs, with the exception of:
>
> - `extension` ( `getURL` , `inIncognitoContext` , `lastError` , `onRequest` , `sendRequest` )
> - `i18n`
> - `runtime` ( `connect` , `getManifest` , `getURL` , `id` , `onConnect` , `onMessage` , `sendMessage` )
> - `storage`

If you don't have a background page yet and are worried about possible performance impacts, look into [Event pages (manifest V2)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) or [Event pages (manifest V3)](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/background_pages/).

Comment: New link for "Event pages": https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/background_pages/